# How to copy war files from repository to inside conatiner in dockerfile using glob pattern?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, devops, glob

I was writing a docker file to copy some war files in the webapps folder of tomcat container. The war files are contained inside target folder after maven build.

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION=2.29
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT_MANAGER-${BUILD_VERSION}/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

How can I remove the build version and write something like

```
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT_MANAGER-*/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

I want to remove the build number as I want to automate the docker build and copy the files irrespective of build version.
One approach I tried and which worked was :

```
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT_MANAGER-[0-9].[0-9][0-9]/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

But the problem is that it would apply only to the files in ?.?? format and not for ??.?? or other format. Also, regex cant be used as dockerfile used glob pattern and not regex pattern .

Comment: `write something like` so just write exactly that?

Comment: Sorry, Didnt understand what you meant

Comment: Write exactly `COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT_MANAGER-*/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps`.

Comment: This did not work . ERROR : - error from sender: readdir: open STUDENT_MANAGER\target\STUDENT_MANAGER-*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Update:- I was able to copy all required files using .dockerfile . I added

```
!*.war
```

to .dockerignore and it copied only the required file.
The copy statement looks like:

```
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT_MANAGER-* /opt/tomcat/webapps
```